# Get organizational unit from CSV of Office attribute powershell

Tags: powershell

Im not sure why I cannot get this to work, but I have a .csv of office. I want to get organizational unit from CSV of Office attribute powershell. however I would like to exclude specific OU from it.  OU :  OU=CompanyIT,OU=COMPANY,DC=contoso,DC=com

e.g OU structure :

```
COMPANY
   ---SALES
   ---IT
        ---SOFTWARE
   ---CompanyIT
```

Input file :

```
Office
IT Office 12
Sales Office
```

My script :

```
    $userIDs = Import-CSV $CSV
    foreach($userID in $userIDs)
{ 
    Get-ADUser -Filter "Office -eq $($userID.Office)" -Properties DistinguishedName 
}
```

My desired output :

```
User,Office,DN
John,IT Office 12,OU=IT,OU=COMPANY,DC=contoso,DC=com
Maria,Sales Office,OU=SALES,OU=COMPANY,DC=contoso,DC=com
```

Comment: Please show the first three lines (sanitized) of the import CSV file.

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: BTW , I would like to exclude specific OU from it.OU=CompanyIT,OU=COMPANY,DC=contoso,DC=com

Comment: It's still not clear.. Your input file does not show the user (samaccountnames). Should the code get these from the members of the groups?  Is the desired DN the DN of the user or the group?

Comment: not group I want to get DN of the user.  I need to get the DN information from the Office field for all active users (samaccountname beginning with CMP prefix)such as  OU=IT,OU=COMPANY,DC=contoso,DC=com formatted.

Comment: Then I think @Itchydon solved it. If so, please don't forget to accept it by clicking the checkmark icon.

Comment: @Theo  Unfortunately , my issue is not solved. I want to get OU information instead of DN.  So I have written it in my above desired output such as OU=IT,OU=COMPANY,DC=contoso,DC=com.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly the `userids` variables are confusing things.  If I change the variable names to office it makes it clearer

```
$Offices = Import-CSV $CSV
foreach($office in $offices){ 
     Get-ADUser -Filter "Office -eq '$($office.Office)'" -Properties office |
     where {$_.DistinguishedName -notlike "OU=CompanyIT,OU=COMPANY,DC=contoso,DC=com"}| 
     select samaccountname,office, @{l="OU";e={($_.distinguishedname -split "," | select -skip 1) -join ","}}    
}
```

Comment: Thanks , I want to use filtering like that. Am I correct ?  {(emailaddress -like "*@contoso.com") -and (Enabled -eq $true) -and (sAMAccountName -like "STUFF*") -and ("Office -eq $($office.Office))}

Comment: for filtering use syntax like this (don't use the curly braces): "emailaddress -like '*@contoso.com' -and Enabled -eq '$true' -and ..."

Comment: BTW , I am getting  Get-ADUser : Error parsing query: 'Office

Comment: Sorry I was missing the single quotes around `'$($office.Office)'`.  Answer updated

Comment: thanks also , I want to use "emailaddress -like '*@contoso.com' -and Enabled -eq '$true' -and Office -eq '$($office.Office)'"  But  office field is returning as null

Comment: I want to get OU information instead of DN. So I have written it in my above desired output such as OU=IT,OU=COMPANY,DC=contoso,DC=com.

Comment: What if you run it as I wrote it without any extra conditions - is it still empty?  Have you checked the users actually have an office assigned?  Is the header in your csv named office

Comment: @Arbelac DN information is the OU path - I don't understand what you are asking?

Comment: At this time , script is returning  like that - >CN John,OU=IT,OU=COMPANY,DC=contoso,DC=com      I want to get it in my above desired output such as OU=IT,OU=COMPANY,DC=contoso,DC=com So script will split CN part

Comment: code updated - have added a calculated property using split to remove first element of distinguishedname